# The length of the edge doesn't show correctly!

Tags: edges, dimensions

What did I do wrong? Any suggestions?[image: any suggestions?]

Comment: What value are you expecting?

Comment: You did nothing wrong. The conversion from binary to decimal numbers may very well end up with floating point errors. [floating points gui](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: Related https://blenderartists.org/t/is-0-999-equal-to-1/318626/48

Comment: If the middle edge is 7.99999mm, then three edges together should be 1.299999cm not 1.3cm

Comment: I understand that 0.99999 is equally to 1 but my problem is. A start with single face, a extrude the face to 2.5mm then I extrude to 8mm then extrude again with 2.5 length and when I measure the 8mm blender show that is 7.9999mm (I know they are the same) But my question is why blender show 7.9999mm why not 8mm?